# why does typescript function parameter type infer failed?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, type-inference, typescript-generics

```
class Base<T> {
    public state = {} as T;
    public getState(): T {
        return this.state
    }
    public setState(v: T) {
        this.state = v
    }
}

interface DogProps {
    name: 'hello';
    age: 123;
}

class Dog extends Base<DogProps> {
    public sayName() {
        console.log('name: ', this.state.name);
    }
    public sayAge() {
        console.log('age: ', this.state.age);
    }
}

function test<U, T extends Base<U>>(Cor: new () => T): [U, T] {
    const dog = new Cor();
    const state = dog.getState();
    return [state, dog];
}

const [state1, dog1] = test(Dog); // state1 is unknow

const [state2, dog2] = test<DogProps, Dog>(Dog); // verbose but right
```

[demo playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

I am newbe in typescript.
I thought the code I wrote was right. But it does not work as expected.
Why state1's type is unknow?
Can I get the right type without `test<DogProps, Dog>(Dog)`?

much thanks!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a side effect of how generic resolution works, typescript sees that `T` is referred to in the arguments so it tries to resolve it, but the constraint is based on `U` so it tries to resolve that first.  Because `U` doesn't appear anywhere in the argument list, it can't resolve it so it ends up `unknown`

If you ensure that `U` is present in the arguments list you can ensure that typescript will be able to resolve it from just looking at the input without having to figure out `T` first:

```
function test<U, T extends Base<U>>(Cor: new()=>(T & Base<U>)): [U, T] {
                                                 // ^here^
}
```

This should fix the issue :)

Comment: You are my god. You saved my life.

Comment: I sure hope your life doesn't depend on something like this .  Happy coding! 

Comment: Now I understood the first paragraph, the reason why my code does not work.
But I still not understand the second paragraph, why your code works.
Especially `without having to figure out T first`. Because return param still need type T.
Could you explain more details?

Comment: pretend you are typescript, you are looking at the types of arguments and you are trying to figure out what `U` should resolve to.  But `U` isn't specified anywhere in the input arguments, only `T`, so how can you figure out what `U` is?  At some point typescript will probably get updated to be able to cope with this case but at least for today using `(T & (Constraint of T))` works fine.

Comment: As a human being, we know `Dog extends Base`, then `U's type` must be `DogProps`. But typescript seems not smart enough. By the way, could you recommend any books or website or articles to learn advanced typescript skills, like `how generic resolution works`. It seems that typescript document does not have these things.

Comment: Sorry I don't have any references, most of the stuff I've picked up has been from experimentation with the online [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play). sorry I couldn't give you more general help.