# how to accept a generic tuple as a parameter and return a genaric containing the generic types

Tags: typescript

So now that typescript 4 is out I expected this to be easier but I still have not found a way to accomplish this.

I am trying to make a function that takes in a tuple containing a specific Generic and returns a Generic returning containing the values.

```
interface STORE<T> {
  data: T;
}

const merge = <U extends any, T extends readonly STORE<U>[]>(values: T): STORE<U[]> =>
  values.reduce<STORE<U[]>>(
    (acc, item) => {
      return { data: [...acc.data, item.data] };
    },
    { data: [] },
  );
```

for example calling this should result in the following

```
assert(merge([{ data: 'test' }, { data: 2 }]), { data: ['test', 2]});
```

This however will return the value as `STORE<unknown[]>` instead of maintaining the type from the input.

Comment: Please publish full example in TS playground

Comment: Without a [mcve] including at least toy definitions for `TYPEONE` and `TYPETWO` it's hard to answer this.  The right answer is likely to be using just one type parameter in the function, but I'm not able to verify anything without a reproducible example here.

Comment: @captain-yossarian
i have updated the question to provide and example

Comment: @jcalz  i have updated the question to provide and example

Comment: I think  these answers might be helpful for you: 1) 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63325817/typescript-return-type-of-unknown-merge-of-objects/63326167#63326167

2) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50374908/transform-union-type-to-intersection-type/50375286#50375286

Answer (score 0):

see [why does typescript function parameter type infer failed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63923831/why-does-typescript-function-parameter-type-infer-failed/63924050#63924050)

By using `T & (constraint of T)` may solve your problem:

```
const merge = <U extends any, T extends readonly STORE<U>[]>(
  values: T & readonly STORE<U>[],
         // ^ here to ---- here ^
): STORE<U[]> => values.reduce<STORE<U[]>>((acc, item) => {
    return {data: [...acc.data, item.data]};  
  }, {data: []})


interface STORE<T> {
  data: T;
}
```

Comment: this does not work with the example above i simply get `Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)` on the second entry in the array.